# fill a Matrix with values from a large dataframe using the row- and column as indicators

Tags: r

I have a big Dataset and want to put (and shrink) it into a Matrix. Is there a way to use the row- and columnnames as indicators for my matrix-filling? For example I have a 3x12 Matrix and my columns are month (1:12) and my rows are names (Bill, Linda, Peter).

```
Just a made up Data-Frame

   name   month
   Bill   1
   Bill   5
   Linda  6
   Linda  8
   Linda  12
   Peter  9
   Peter  5
   Peter  2
   Peter  1
```

How can I tell r without using a loop to add +1 to the correct cell if the combination matches.

Is there any way that r compares the row and column names with values from given vectors without using some kind of a loop?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df
#     name month
# 1:  Bill     1
# 2:  Bill     5
# 3: Linda     6
# 4: Linda     8
# 5: Linda    12
# 6: Peter     9
# 7: Peter     5
# 8: Peter     2
# 9: Peter     1

df_wide <- 
  dcast(df[data.table(month = 1:12), on = .(month)],
        name ~ month, fun.aggregate = function(x) as.integer(sum(!is.na(x)) > 0),
        value.var = 'name')[!is.na(name)]

mat <- as.matrix(df_wide[, -'name'])
rownames(mat) <- df_wide$name

mat

#       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
# Bill  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0
# Linda 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0  0  0  1
# Peter 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1  0  0  0
```

Comment: Wow. I could never have done that. thank you very much!